# Multiprocessing race sharing a variable

Tags: c, unix, operating-system

I'm doing a simple Producer/Consumer problem. I have a producer(chef) that produces portions when consumer(savage) consumes all of them, so a savage has to wait until chef fills the pot. I don't understand what's my error because savages consume portions, but chef doesn't fill the pot.

This is the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int shmid, semid;
int *portions;
sem_t *mutex, *empty, *full;

char sem_1[]= "mutex";
char sem_2[]= "full";
char sem_3[]= "empty";

void clear()
{

   if (shmctl(shmid,IPC_RMID,0) == -1) perror("shmctl");
}

void producer(int num, int m)   
{
  int i;

   while(1) { 


    }    
}

void consumer(int num, int rounds)   
{

       int i;



}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

int i;
int N, M, NROUNDS, pid;


if (argc != 4)
{
    fprintf(stderr,"insert N savages, M portions e NROUNDS\n");
    exit(1);
}

N=atoi(argv[1]);
M=atoi(argv[2]);
NROUNDS=atoi(argv[3]);




/* generate producer and consumers */




      }

  for(i=0;i<N;i++) {
    pid=wait(NULL);
    printf("Terminate process %d\n", pid);
  }   

  clear();

}
```

This is the output:

```
./a.out 3 5 3

Savage[2] eats
Number of portions in pot: 4
Savage[1] eats
Number of portions in pot: 3
Savage[0] eats
Number of portions in pot: 2
Savage[2] eats
Number of portions in pot: 1
Savage[1] eats
Number of portions in pot: 0
Savage[0] eats
Number of portions in pot: -1
Savage[2] eats
Number of portions in pot: -2
Terminate process 10287
Savage[1] eats
Number of portions in pot: -3
Savage[0] eats
Number of portions in pot: -4
Terminate process 10285
Terminate process 10286
```

Comment: Are you sure that semaphores are the correct synchronization mechanism to use?  Consider condition variables...

Answer (score 1):

Your consumer takes the mutex, signals that the pot is empty and then never releases the mutex, in this way, the producer can never take the mutex and fill the pot and your process will deadlock.

[For a better understanding, read the Producer Consumer section in this great book.](https://www.google.be/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjy76zVwbHWAhXMPFAKHQnhBY0QFggtMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fgreenteapress.com%2Fsemaphores%2FLittleBookOfSemaphores.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGZLhXbpHIWv9OlMLaBdb3u2XVXyQ)

Comment: If I change that with this, the program doesn't start:   if((*portions)==0) {                                                                                                                                 sem_post(mutex)                                                                                       sem_post(empty)                                                                                       sem_wait(full)

Comment: Read the book I linked, your algorithm probably has more than 1 issue.